# onclick function in a dynamic generated html not working for windows phone phonegap app

Tags: jquery, cordova, dynamic-html

Following code does not working in windows mobile but working fine in android and ios apps.

```
    $.each(category.sub_categories, function(index2, subcategory) {
                var subCatName = subcategory.name;
                $("#test-listview" + index).append('<li><a onclick=\"parseSubCategory(' + subcategory.id + ',\'' + subCatName + '\');\" href="#product_List">' + subcategory.name + '</a></li>');

            });
```

Comment: bind event listener from javascript ..

Comment: Learn [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @Satpal can you give a sample code with parse values using onclick evvent.